# How to add checkboxes in dropdown list MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to add checkbox in my drop downlist.
I googled it and I am getting example in asp.net as I am trying to  do in MVC3.
On my form edit User must be able to check values in the dropdown list.
  For example in below form for manufactures list  currently it is just displaying values I must provide with a checkbox associated with that value.

My form:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EmsAdmin.Models.User>" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="EmsAdmin.Models" %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    // Focus on the first input box for the site
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#UserId').focus();
    });
  //]]>
</script>

<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
  <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Id,"Id:") %>
    <%: Model.Id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.PersonId,"Person:") %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.PersonId, (SelectList)ViewData["allPersons"], "Select a person", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Person,"") %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Email,"Email:") %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Email, new { @style = "width:250px;" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Email,"") %>
  </p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Approve,"Aprrove User:") %>
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(e=> e.Approve,Model.Approve) %><span>&nbsp;Switch this on if you want to add regitrar </span>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Approve,"") %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.ManufacturerDescription,"Brand:") %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.ManufacturerDescription, (SelectList)ViewData["allManufacturers"], "Select  Brands", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.ManufacturerDescription,"") %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.CountryName,"Country:") %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.CountryName, (SelectList)ViewData["allCountries"], "Select Countries", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.CountryName,"") %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Role,"Role:") %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Role, (SelectList)ViewData["allRoles"], "Select Roles", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Role,"") %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Cancel","Details",new {id=Model.Id},new {@title="exit without saving"}) %>
  </p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Please add comment and do down vote. Thanks

Comment: fyi, you're missing a `<p>` above your `Approve User:` (noticed while I reformatted)

Comment: @BradChristie Thankyou I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **base** html input such as dropdown with checkboxes. You can use side-part control libraries like DevExpress or make your own control.

Look here for [jquery plugin](http://lab.arc90.com/tools/jquery_multiselect/) which override base  markup.